# Google App Engine: How to Set Default Value from a property to another property in db.Model Class?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

My App having db class,

```
class invoice(db.Model):
   location_code = db.StringProperty()
   invoice_no = db.IntegerProperty()
   product_tax_rate = db.FloatProperty()
   basic_tax_rate = db.FloatProperty()
   addl_tax_rate = db.FloatProperty()
   .
   .
   .
```

In this, i wanted to set **product_tax_rate**'s value as default value for property **basic_tax_rate**'s property if **addl_tax_rate**'s value is **0**.

How can i add a generic procedure for this logic in this class method?

Please let me know if you still not getting this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NDB and [ComputedProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties?hl=ca#computed) todo something like:

```
class invoice(ndb.Model):
   product_tax_rate = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.basic_tax_rate if self.addl_tax_rate == 0 else ???)
   basic_tax_rate = ndb.FloatProperty()
   addl_tax_rate = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

Comment: Dear, Can i use both db and ndb in same class model?

Comment: Yeah, Actually i use this script in my db but it throwing some error message as 'module' object has no attribute 'ComputedProperty'

any reason of this error?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a model hook: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks

> By defining a hook, an application can run some code before or after some type of operations; for example, a Model might run some function before every get().

So when addl_tax_rate is 0 you just need some logic that would set the values accordingly when the model is put into the datastore. Something like:

```
def _pre_put_hook(self):
if self.addl_tax_rate == 0:
    self.basic_tax_rate = self.product_tax_rate
```

That code is not tested.

Comment: Thanks for prompt ans, but its not working for me, i guess because of am not using here ndb model.. do you agree?

Comment: But we dont want to use ndb here, Couldn't it possible without ndb?

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use ndb instead?

Comment: I'm sure you could work something out on the __/constructor side of things but I can't help you out I'm afraid. So far ndb has provided natively all I need.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it manually in the code where you create new instances of your entity. Or override the constructor (but that sounds like it would just be leading you on to more debugging mysteries).

Comment: yeh..manual code is the last option, bt am actually looking for some generic code to handle these type of scenario..